# Do you need skirt boards on the stairs?

Tags: trim, stairs

My stairs are flush with the drywall right now. Will this cause me issues down the road?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to install skirt boards.  Just like you don't have to install any molding in your house.

However there is a difference here compared to your normal baseboards.

- you are usually moving with more force on stairs.
- you are closer to the walls when on stairs.  You don't usually walk next to walls in your house much except for hallways.
- if you damaged the bottom area of a wall by kicking it, well that is a pretty easy fix.  The drywall next to the stairs will not be as easy to patch and you may notice it a lot more.
- you are often carrying things up and down the steps.  These nick this area and also cause your feet to hit the walls.
- and then if you have baseboards already they look much better than when they meet a stair skirt.

Note that this is highly dependent on what function the stairs play and the overall finishes in the house.  If you are doing a high end house it is ludicrous to skip stair skirts.  On the other end if you have stairs going to an unfinished basement, generally not needed.